# MS Word VBA - Range with size of 1 but text of length 0, what's in it?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have found a MS Word range that is not collapsed, its size is 1 but the length of it's text is 0.  If it contains no text then what is in the range?  What's going on here?

Here is the code that found such a range.

```
Public Function FindLeft(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal char As Integer) As Range

    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = rng.Document

    Dim i As Long
    For i = rng.Start To rng.End - 1

        Dim r As Range
        Set r = doc.Range(i, i + 1) ' Range is non-empty

        Debug.Assert Len(r.text) > 0 ' This should never fail but did.

        If Asc(r.text) = char Then
            Set FindLeft = r
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next

    Set FindLeft = Nothing

End Function
```

#### Update

I have found ranges with sizes of over a hundred but still null text.  The only way to delete such ranges is to set their text to `vbnullstring` or `""`

Comment: Formatting.  This is actually why you need to work with discrete ranges in Word VBA instead of just the text.

Comment: @Comintern, by discrete ranges you `WdUnits` instead of indexes?  Also, why does the formatting have it's own range?  I thought formatting was a property of range.

Comment: By discrete ranges I mean anything obtained by using `Document.Range` instead of pure text manipulation. As far as the "why", I stopped asking that about the Word object model years ago.  I suspect hacks on top of hacks under the hood.

Comment: Can be various things such as content controls, fields, collaborative editing marks, hidden text, but don't expect to find any exhaustive documentation about it. Post your document and we can tell you what's in it in that specific case. In your code you should not rely on the fact that a non-empty range contains text.

Comment: Probably just the paragraph marker